# How do I keep a text file under maximum size limit?

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, size

Each time my main program runs, it writes around 6 lines (around 50 characters in total) to a log file.

How can I keep this file from growing endlessly?  I'd like to keep the file under 2MB with new text being added to the end of the file and text at the beginning of the file being removed.

Comment: Is this a solicitation for votes? Either way, it doesn't appear to be a question and should be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not actually a question.

Comment: There, i made it a question. This kind of "ask yourself" is the proper way to share something on SO.

Comment: @Pickled - do try to make it more of a question and describe the usage and requirements you had.

Comment: Why not just put the solution into the question, if that is the thing you want us to discuss of?

Comment: @Bolu - no, that's not how SO wants it. Read the FAQ.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You rightly removed irrelevant commentary, but your edit didn't make it a question, and actually made the grammar quite a bit worse than it was originally.  Have a look, this is now a real question, with all the essential details preserved.

Comment: Yes, I was (am) lazy. I left most of the OPs wording intact.

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo txtfile = new FileInfo(nameOfFile);
if (txtfile.Length > (2 * 1024 * 1024))       // ## NOTE: 2MB max file size
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(nameOfFile).Skip(10).ToArray();  // ## Set to 10 lines
    File.WriteAllLines(nameOfFile, lines);
}
```

The above piece of code will only run if the file is over 2MB (size, not size on disk). It will remove the first 10 lines from the file and write the remaining lines back into the file.

I have managed to get this to work how I need it to with a fairly small piece of code and thought I would share it here to help reduce people asking the same question.
Hopefully it will help people with the same issue.

I have not found any issues with this process for my solution yet, but please feel free to add any comments if this is incorrect.

Comment: What if it's still more than 2MB after deleting the 10 first lines? What if you only had to delete 1 line to keep the correct size? There are numerous other issues I can think of here as well, so I am afraid this is a solution that is quite specific to your case, and will not work as a general solution.

Comment: This solution waste lot of memory. You should use streams for this.

Comment: @Aik Not streams; instead, using [`File.ReadLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) (the Enumerable overload) will avoid buffering the entire file in memory.

Comment: my program only adds about 6 lines of text each time its run, in total around 50 characters. This is a very simple option for small files only.

Comment: @MatthewWatson for someone new to C# files, can you give example code for using streams to delete the first X lines?

Comment: @TKoL It's exactly the same as the code shown above, except using `File.ReadLines()` instead of `File.ReadAllLines()`.The `Skip(10)` is the thing that removes the first 10 lines.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks!

Answer (score -3):

For Web Application you can also define the value for maximum request length.

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15000" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Which seems not very related to logfiles.